# sqlite3 executemany in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to bulk insert from python, but each time I get the same error, "incorrect number of bindings supplied". I tried passing it as (results,) but does the same.

```
results = [x for x in pool.map(check_server, serverlist) if x is not None]

cursor.executemany("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO server_errors(ip) values(?)", results)

print(str(results))
['102.103.13.23', '102.123.222.125', '1.123.222.123']
```

Comment: You need each IP in its own sublist. `executemany` expects nested iterables. In this case, the inner timetable is the string itself, so it tries to unpack each string, character-by-character into a single placeholder

Comment: `[(x,) for x in ...]` might work as intended?

Comment: @shawn ahhhh so simple. Many thanks!